# Python k- Nearest Neighbours

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, knn

I'm trying to translate code for k Nearest Neighbors from R to Python. I'm having trouble with the last few lines, the assigning the classifications. I have a high level understanding of the algorithm, but not sure of some of the details. This is what I've done so far:

```
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import numpy.random as npr
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist, squareform

#define function
def kNN(X,y,k):
    #number of observations
    n = len(y)
    #Set up return values
    y_star = Series(np.zeros(n),dtype='Int64')
    #distance vector
    dist = squareform(pdist(X,metric='Euclidean'))
    #so it can't choose itself as a closest neighbour
    np.fill_diagonal(dist,1e10)
    #Loop through each observation
    for i in range(n):
    #Find the y values of the k nearest neighbours
    y_nearest = y[dist[i,:].argsort()[:k]]
    #assign y_hat
    if y_nearest.mean()> 0.5:
        y_hat[i] = 1
    #return the predicted classification
    return y_hat
```

Error given when tested:

```
ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type <class      'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

Comment: Could you include the import statements?

Comment: Obvious mention of [the algorithm in scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html).

Comment: @Carsten I'm trying to learn the algorithm step-by-step to check I understand it completely

Comment: The code is not correct and gives an error when tested. I think the problem is lies in the last few lines of the code, the "the assign y_hat" part.

    ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type <class      'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: The `y_star` should probably be `y_hat` and the indentation of the for-loop is missing. But I think the real problem is that somewhere along the way you try do an operation that isn't supported by Pandas. For this calculation Numpy arrays are better suited.